# Osmosis ignoring data in generating .map

Tags: android, openstreetmap, mapsforge, osmosis

I'm trying to convert an OSM file that it needed to be developed with private data to the format .map using `osmosis` with `mapforge-map-writer`, but the data for the survey point are being totally ignored in `.map` generation. I've investigated the code, but I can't understand what is happening.

I've used the following command:

`./osmosis --rx file = lotes.osm --mapfile-writing file = lotes.map`

I set the entry of bounds, yet nothing is being placed in the generated .map.

Below is the map to build the references of bounds:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<osm version='0.6' upload='true' generator='JOSM'>
  <bounds minlat="-8.156" minlon="-35.008" maxlat="-7.931" maxlon="-33.865"/>
  <node id='-32' action='modify' visible='true' version="11" timestamp="2008-01-02T03:04:05Z" uid="20" user="user20" lat='-8.06393367554' lon='-34.88970060001' />
  <node id='-33' action='modify' visible='true' version="11" timestamp="2008-01-02T03:04:05Z" uid="20" user="user20" lat='-8.06083075789' lon='-34.88378983943' />
  <node id='-35' action='modify' visible='true' version="11" timestamp="2008-01-02T03:04:05Z" uid="20" user="user20" lat='-8.06409078466' lon='-34.87984272078' />
  <node id='-37' action='modify' visible='true' version="11" timestamp="2008-01-02T03:04:05Z" uid="20" user="user20" lat='-8.06758644682' lon='-34.88739976703' />
  <node id='-41' action='modify' visible='true' version="11" timestamp="2008-01-02T03:04:05Z" uid="20" user="user20" lat='-8.06793993906' lon='-34.88718158459' />
  <node id='-42' action='modify' visible='true' version="11" timestamp="2008-01-02T03:04:05Z" uid="20" user="user20" lat='-8.06432644823' lon='-34.87960470357' />
  <node id='-44' action='modify' visible='true' version="11" timestamp="2008-01-02T03:04:05Z" uid="20" user="user20" lat='-8.06778283143' lon='-34.87599477597' />
  <node id='-46' action='modify' visible='true' version="11" timestamp="2008-01-02T03:04:05Z" uid="20" user="user20" lat='-8.07208363064' lon='-34.88442455197' />
  <node id='-50' action='modify' visible='true' version="11" timestamp="2008-01-02T03:04:05Z" uid="20" user="user20" lat='-8.06411042329' lon='-34.88999812152' />
  <node id='-51' action='modify' visible='true' version="11" timestamp="2008-01-02T03:04:05Z" uid="20" user="user20" lat='-8.06774355452' lon='-34.88777662761' />
  <node id='-53' action='modify' visible='true' version="11" timestamp="2008-01-02T03:04:05Z" uid="20" user="user20" lat='-8.07035546112' lon='-34.89225928496' />
  <node id='-55' action='modify' visible='true' version="11" timestamp="2008-01-02T03:04:05Z" uid="20" user="user20" lat='-8.06629030595' lon='-34.89446094411' />
  <node id='-59' action='modify' visible='true' version="11" timestamp="2008-01-02T03:04:05Z" uid="20" user="user20" lat='-8.06045762062' lon='-34.88329397025' />
  <node id='-60' action='modify' visible='true' version="11" timestamp="2008-01-02T03:04:05Z" uid="20" user="user20" lat='-8.06405150738' lon='-34.87920800823' />
  <node id='-62' action='modify' visible='true' version="11" timestamp="2008-01-02T03:04:05Z" uid="20" user="user20" lat='-8.06204836132' lon='-34.8744674989' />
  <node id='-64' action='modify' visible='true' version="11" timestamp="2008-01-02T03:04:05Z" uid="20" user="user20" lat='-8.05876867919' lon='-34.87968404264' />
  <way id='-34' action='modify' visible='true' version="11" timestamp="2008-01-02T03:04:05Z" uid="20" user="user20">
    <nd ref='-32' />
    <nd ref='-33' />
    <nd ref='-35' />
    <nd ref='-37' />
    <nd ref='-32' />
    <tag k='DSQFL' v='154' />
  </way>
  <way id='-43' action='modify' visible='true' version="11" timestamp="2008-01-02T03:04:05Z" uid="20" user="user20">
    <nd ref='-41' />
    <nd ref='-42' />
    <nd ref='-44' />
    <nd ref='-46' />
    <nd ref='-41' />
    <tag k='DSQFL' v='160' />
  </way>
  <way id='-52' action='modify' visible='true' version="11" timestamp="2008-01-02T03:04:05Z" uid="20" user="user20">
    <nd ref='-50' />
    <nd ref='-51' />
    <nd ref='-53' />
    <nd ref='-55' />
    <nd ref='-50' />
    <tag k='DSQFL' v='153' />
  </way>
  <way id='-61' action='modify' visible='true' version="11" timestamp="2008-01-02T03:04:05Z" uid="20" user="user20">
    <nd ref='-59' />
    <nd ref='-60' />
    <nd ref='-62' />
    <nd ref='-64' />
    <nd ref='-59' />
    <tag k='DSQFL' v='155' />
  </way>
</osm>
```

But when I see the binary file generated, open through a hex editor I can't see the tags placed.

While other files directly downloaded at **OpenStreetMaps** site can be converted without problems.

What is wrong to `osmosis` ignore these polygons?

Comment: Maybe due to their negative ids?

Comment: No, I had tested with positives IDs and nothing changed.

Comment: osmosis doesn't has a `--mapfile-writing` option so you must be either talking about some other program or about some other option.

Comment: When you install mapforger-map-writer.jar it allows you to use this command as the following link: https://github.com/mapsforge/mapsforge/blob/master/docs/Getting-Started-Map-Writer.md

Answer (score 0):

After much trying to get to see the solution in case the mapsforge -map- writer.jar takes into account the OpenStreetMaps tags , according to an increasing discussion in https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mapsforge-dev/TGAMrGjCZuk.

Based on this information when adding the tag **< tag k='building' v='yes' / >** in one of the polygons it was displayed after generating the **.map**.

Below it should be the OSM file so that it can be generated in the .map format:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<osm version='0.6' upload='true' generator='JOSM'>
  <bounds minlat='-8.155149' minlon='-35.01865' maxlat='-7.926358' maxlon='-34.851208' origin='Osmosis 0.35' />
  <node id='-8' action='modify' visible='true' lat='-8.32238189013' lon='-35.05999269907' />
  <node id='-10' action='modify' visible='true' lat='-8.3428522453' lon='-35.00838893999' />
  <node id='-12' action='modify' visible='true' lat='-8.37122527763' lon='-35.00283519056' />
  <node id='-14' action='modify' visible='true' lat='-8.40577539618' lon='-35.06303932724' />
  <node id='-16' action='modify' visible='true' lat='-8.33679523492' lon='-35.00150986399' />
  <node id='-18' action='modify' visible='true' lat='-8.37376026759' lon='-34.99464341014' />
  <node id='-20' action='modify' visible='true' lat='-8.3757582776' lon='-34.94819386942' />
  <node id='-22' action='modify' visible='true' lat='-8.33639559383' lon='-34.95950332282' />
  <node id='-24' action='modify' visible='true' lat='-8.37435662533' lon='-34.98077936883' />
  <node id='-26' action='modify' visible='true' lat='-8.41432500277' lon='-35.06264910335' />
  <node id='-28' action='modify' visible='true' lat='-8.37749469974' lon='-35.00250946639' />
  <node id='-30' action='modify' visible='true' lat='-8.38174452833' lon='-34.94630754375' />
  <node id='-32' action='modify' visible='true' lat='-8.42317791951' lon='-34.97100775179' />
  <node id='-34' action='modify' visible='true' lat='-8.33641063351' lon='-34.95382499837' />
  <node id='-36' action='modify' visible='true' lat='-8.37891131443' lon='-34.93986401122' />
  <node id='-38' action='modify' visible='true' lat='-8.4245943674' lon='-34.96599611538' />
  <node id='-40' action='modify' visible='true' lat='-8.42778135618' lon='-34.90585647842' />
  <node id='-42' action='modify' visible='true' lat='-8.33216031093' lon='-34.8983390238' />
  <node id='-44' action='modify' visible='true' lat='-8.31267907528' lon='-35.05548962276' />
  <node id='-46' action='modify' visible='true' lat='-8.32790994217' lon='-35.00716312877' />
  <node id='-48' action='modify' visible='true' lat='-8.28788337586' lon='-35.01253273921' />
  <node id='-50' action='modify' visible='true' lat='-8.2861121946' lon='-35.05692151887' />
  <node id='-52' action='modify' visible='true' lat='-8.28930031512' lon='-35.00716312877' />
  <node id='-54' action='modify' visible='true' lat='-8.32861834017' lon='-35.00179351833' />
  <node id='-56' action='modify' visible='true' lat='-8.32897253869' lon='-34.95847866076' />
  <node id='-58' action='modify' visible='true' lat='-8.32507633736' lon='-34.89941294589' />
  <node id='-60' action='modify' visible='true' lat='-8.29036301622' lon='-34.90335066021' />
  <way id='-62' action='modify' visible='true'>
    <nd ref='-8' />
    <nd ref='-10' />
    <nd ref='-12' />
    <nd ref='-14' />
    <nd ref='-8' />
    <tag k='DSQFL' v='154' />
    <tag k='building' v='yes' />
  </way>
  <way id='-64' action='modify' visible='true'>
    <nd ref='-16' />
    <nd ref='-18' />
    <nd ref='-24' />
    <nd ref='-20' />
    <nd ref='-22' />
    <nd ref='-16' />
    <tag k='DSQFL' v='153' />
    <tag k='building' v='yes' />
  </way>
  <way id='-66' action='modify' visible='true'>
    <nd ref='-26' />
    <nd ref='-28' />
    <nd ref='-30' />
    <nd ref='-32' />
    <nd ref='-26' />
    <tag k='building' v='yes' />
  </way>
  <way id='-68' action='modify' visible='true'>
    <nd ref='-34' />
    <nd ref='-36' />
    <nd ref='-38' />
    <nd ref='-40' />
    <nd ref='-42' />
    <nd ref='-34' />
    <tag k='building' v='yes' />
  </way>
  <way id='-70' action='modify' visible='true'>
    <nd ref='-44' />
    <nd ref='-46' />
    <nd ref='-48' />
    <nd ref='-50' />
    <nd ref='-44' />
    <tag k='building' v='yes' />
  </way>
  <way id='-72' action='modify' visible='true'>
    <nd ref='-52' />
    <nd ref='-54' />
    <nd ref='-56' />
    <nd ref='-58' />
    <nd ref='-60' />
    <nd ref='-52' />
    <tag k='building' v='yes' />
  </way>
  <relation id='-74' action='modify' visible='true'>
    <member type='way' ref='-68' role='outer' />
    <member type='way' ref='-62' role='outer' />
    <member type='way' ref='-64' role='outer' />
    <member type='way' ref='-72' role='outer' />
    <member type='way' ref='-66' role='outer' />
    <member type='way' ref='-70' role='outer' />
    <tag k='type' v='multipolygon' />
  </relation>
</osm>
```